# Where to find the IP address for a Windows Azure preview web site

Tags: azure, dns, ip-address, azure-web-app-service

For a web site published using the Quick Create feature of the new [Windows Azure preview portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), how do I get the IP address to create the A records for the DNS entry for the site? The [help](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) says, "You can discover this IP address from within the Windows Azure Management Portal." But I can't find said address anywhere. Can I just ping the `mysite.azurewebsites.net` address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a Windows Azure Website (shared) in Windows Azure Preview Portal, the website is created as a shared website which is part of hundred other websites on a Windows Server Farm. With Windows Azure Website (shared), you can not set custom domain name for your website. That's why you don't see a IP address listed to this website at preview portal.

Once you change the Windows Azure website to "reserved" mode then website will run on its own Virtual machine (it will not be free and you will be charged 1/3 during preview mode) then you can set CNAME settings for your website.

Finally the help link you suggested above is related with web/worker role as well as for reserved websites.

Comment: Wow! Shared hosting with no support for custom DNS. I've never heard of such a defeatured package. Do you know what  people are expected to use it for? Just for development and testing before going live on a reserved node?

Comment: I would say that websites are still in (FREE) preview phase so it good time to collect any kind of feedback and your comments are exactly the kind of feedback which will shape the final results.

Comment: On the ch9 cloud cover demo of AzureWebsites they flippantly remarked that you can configure CNAME for the site. They didn't mention that you need to go for the paid hosting. I don't mind paying but being mislead so as to waste time head scratching is not good!

Comment: Not to mention that the "reserved" site option is quite expensive (I think 8 cents per hour). Seriously, Microsoft, do you really think people will put low-traffic sites on a shared hosting without custom DNS?

Comment: @StephenChung, actually the "reserved" mode (now called "Standard") doesn't offer nameservers, either.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong!